# How to do FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(bytes, metadata) from firebase_vision_image package of flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, face-detection, firebase-machine-learning

Hi I am using firebase_vision_image package of flutter and right now I do confused, is there a way to change `FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(myImage file)` to `FirebaseVisionImage.fromBytes(bytes, metadata)`? I have used `FirebaseVisionImage.fromFile(myImage file)` and `myImage` here is an image taking from camera but I always get slow respond when image processing.. so here I want to try to convert `myImage` to `bytes,metadata` and I would like to see the differences for both of them or maybe is there a better way to speed the image processing up when image come from camera taking

Comment: Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: Hi @FabASP, I din't find yet any solution for this case